# add specials characters to less file

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less

In my application i use less file

Using visual studio 2013.

In my site i has an handler that make some replace some change in the css files

for example 
@align ==> replace with 'left'
@images ==> replace with the actual folder of the images

my problem is that when the compile make the css file from the less file the compiler  ignore from all unnecessary characters.

In sort how can i add "@align" to the css file that created from the less file

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It is not clear if you want to keep the text `@align` in the resulting CSS file but the compiler replaces it with `left`, or vice versa.

Comment: Yes i want to keep the @align in the resulting css file.

Comment: But `float:@align` doesn't make sense in CSS.

Comment: Like i said before in my site i has an handlers that make some replaces on the css file,
the @align replace to 'left' if the site is left to right, and to 'right' if the site is right to left etc'

Comment: That wasn't very clear in the question, sorry. So you first have the less, which is supposed to output this intermediate kind of css, which is still supposed to contain the @align, then gets handled by the other handler that outputs real css? Pfff, my gut feeling says don't use a @, use something else.